# ASP script tags involving buttons within HTML

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Have a question regarding scripts I've never worked on before. I am trying to get rid of two buttons that seem to be involved in the same script. Inside the body tags, I try to get rid of anything inside of the script, it'll break the page. Tried to do some research on it, but no luck.

This is inside the scripts section

HI, this is the section inside of the body tags

```
 catid = Request.QueryString("id")
 sub productInfo(connObj,category)

 sqlCustomer = "SELECT * FROM qryProdsCategory WHERE ccategory = '" & Cint(category) & "'"
 Set rs = Server.CreateObject ("adodb.Recordset")
 rs.Open sqlCustomer, dbc, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
 if not rs.EOF then
 if Session("sort")="0" then
 rs.sort = "cname ASC"
 end if

 while not rs.EOF

 If rs("stock")="1" then

Response.Write "<form action="&q&Application("secureurl")&"/cart/view-cart.asp"&q&"       method="&q&"POST"&q&" name=form"&i&">"

Response.Write "<a href=""product.asp?id=" & rs("catalogID") & ""

Response.Write "" & rs("catalogID") & "" & rs("manModNum") & "</font></td><td width=""18%"" rowspan=""2"">"
Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fproductid"&q&" value="&q & rs("catalogID")& q&">" 
Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fquantity"&q&" value=1>" 
Response.Write "<input type="&q&"hidden"&q&" name="&q&"fcat"&q&" value=" & rs("ccategory") & ">"

If rs("stock")="" then
Response.Write "<button class=""btn"" TYPE=""btn"" style=""background-color: #cb0000;color:   #fff;"">.</button> </form>" 
Else
Response.Write "<button "">ADD</button></form>" 



End If



End If

rs.MoveNext
wend

else
Response.Write "&nbsp;<P><Center><font size=""2""><h3>Sorry, but products information for the category you have chosen is not available at this moment. Please check back soon!</H3></font></center>"
catname = "Error"
end if

end sub
%>

<!-- INSIDE BODY TAGS BELOW -->

<!-- Start Profile -->
<div class="span3">
<img src="img/team/profile1.jpg">
<div class="productSelection">
<div class="ProductTitle">
<strong style="font-size:16px;">LOREM IPSUM</strong>
</div>
<h6>LOREMIPSUM</h6>
<h6>LOREM IPSUM</h6>

<%
call openConn()
call productInfo(dbc,catid)
%>

</div>
</div>
<!-- End Profile -->
```

Comment: Please fix your format and use 'code samples' for your code to look like code (and have normal newlines).

Comment: Hi, I am not sure on how to actually make it look like standard code. Everytime I do post it, it turns into a regular paragraph. Sorry, I am new to this site.

Comment: use four spaces in the begining of every code line, and check out how it turns out in the box under the box you're writing in. You can also use <br> for newlines. And remove the text: '![Script inside Body][1]'

Comment: Thank you. I just added the small script that is inside the body tags. Two buttons are inside of that script and I am trying to break it up without breaking the page.

Comment: I don't see any buttons here.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am not sure if it's being ran through the script inside of the " <% %> " tags, but those are two buttons attached. My problem is separating the buttons without breaking the page.

Comment: You're going to have to post the `productInfo` code, then. I'm willing to believe that `openConn` just opens a connection, so we probably don't need to see that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders just added the code attached to the page on top. maybe it can help give you a better understanding of what I am trying to get across.

Answer (score 0):

This is some bad code. The code is closing the `form` tag twice.

Since you say you only need one button, and since the `form` tag is either being closed twice or not at all, I think that one of the `Response.Write` statements needs to be in the other `If` branch.

```
'DONT TOUCH THESE BELOW
If rs("stock")="" then
    Response.Write "<button class=""btn"" TYPE=""btn"" style=""background-color: #cb0000;color: #fff;"">ADD TO CART</button> </form>" 
Else
    Response.Write "<button "">ADD TO CART</button></form>" 
'DONT TOUCH THESE ABOVE 

End If
```

Comment: Once i do that, The buttons disappear. I believe that Response.Write is what is attached to the script inside of the body tags. This is what is making it appear. This is where I am kind of confused from.

Comment: Then I'm confused too. Didn't you say you _want_ to get rid of the buttons? Also, BTW, `button` doesn't have a `typ` attribute. There's a `type` attribute, and one of it's values is `button`.

Comment: With that script involving the button you told me to get rid of, It involves two buttons that connect to the " Add To Cart " function of the website. The problem is that TWO buttons are there instead of just one. I need it to show just one and not two. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @cesar: you haven't really told us what you're trying to do! Under what circumstances do you not want to display which button?

Comment: Theres TWO buttons that are in that script that both lead to the " Add To Cart " page. I just need one of them gone. This script somehow is involving both buttons and the issue has been just trying to take one away. that's all.

Comment: See my update. I think you need something a little different.

Comment: the two buttons are still showing up in the same section. Do you believe it has something to do with the script that is given inside of the span 3 Div?

Comment: They can't still be there. Press Control-F5 after you reach the page to flush the browser cache.

Comment: I promise you man, They are still there. That is what is so confusing about this whole thing. Do you see any other errors in the code above? or was that all?

Comment: Aside from the fact that it's ugly Classic ASP code, and that it would be a lot more readable without all the comments, no, I can't see anything.

Comment: I cant post a screenshot of how the page is looking because I need 10 reputation or whatever so I really can't give you a visual right now. I know it's something linked with the script inside of the span 3 box, but if I do edit it, it does break.

Comment: In fact, I suggest you make a backup of that page, then remove the comments, and clean it up. Maybe then you'll be able to read it. Then post the cleaned up version, after testing to see if it still has the same problem.

Comment: I bet you can do a "View Source" of the resulting page, then post everything inside of the `<form>` tags.

Comment: HI John, I've made a backup page and cleaned it up a bit,  but still no luck with getting rid of the 2nd button. Not sure what it can be.